# Change QPushButton behaviour if hotkey is held ?

Tags: pyside, maya

Is it possible to change the appearance  and function of a QPushButton , such as hover , if a hotkey is held ?

I’m after a solution whereby if I held CTRL down , then hovered , then pressed, it would have a different outcome to hover and press

I’m using Pyside currently and this application is for maya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example subclassing `QPushButton`'s enter and leave events. It will change stylesheets when ctrl is held down, and will also execute different function than when ctrl is not pressed:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CustomButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, label, parent=None):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(label, parent)

        self.entered = False  # Track when the cursor enters this widget.

        self.normal_style = "QPushButton {background-color:red;}"
        self.alt_style = "QPushButton {background-color:blue;}"

        self.setStyleSheet(self.normal_style)

        self.clicked.connect(self.click_event)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.entered = True
        self.set_style()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.entered = False
        self.setStyleSheet(self.normal_style)

    def set_style(self):
        if self.entered and self.parent().is_ctrl_down:
            self.setStyleSheet(self.alt_style)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(self.normal_style)

    def func_1(self):
        print "1"

    def func_2(self):
        print "2"

    def click_event(self):
        if self.entered and self.parent().is_ctrl_down:
            self.func_2()
        else:
            self.func_1()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.is_ctrl_down = False  # Track when ctrl is held down.

        self.my_button = CustomButton("Hello World!", parent=self)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.my_button)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Button behaviour example")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        ctrl_state = event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.CTRL
        if ctrl_state != self.is_ctrl_down:
            self.is_ctrl_down = ctrl_state
            self.my_button.set_style()

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.is_ctrl_down = False
        self.my_button.set_style()


tool = Window()
tool.show()
```

I tested this on Maya 2018, so it's in `PySide2`. If you're using an older version with `PySide` you just need minor tweaks to make this example work.

Comment: Many thanks - am trying this out today, I really appreciate the depth you’ve answered thanks

Comment: Even if it's not exactly the behavior you want, hopefully it gives you some ideas on how to approach it. If this has answered your question then don't forget to accept it so others know that it has been resolved.

Comment: I’ve discovered the Pyside difference ( namely there’s not a QtWidgets separate module ?) so just had to tweak that a little

Comment: Yes they're almost the same :). `PySide2` has `shiboken2` instead of `shiboken`, and most widget classes are moved to `QtWidgets`. A few methods are renamed too and I remember Signals were slightly different. Glad you got it working!